# Connect to websocket server without specifying port

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, tls

I'm trying to create a secure node.js server without a websocket server on the same port. The port is 8080.

I can access the url in the browser and I can connect to websockets when I specify the port.

https://ws.site.com // Works
wss://ws.site.com // Don't work
wss://ws.site.com:8080 // Works

Why is this? What am I doing wrong? This is the nginx config

```
upstream ws.site.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name ws.site.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/myserver.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location / {
            access_log off;

            proxy_pass https://ws.site.com;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The `wss://` URL handler uses the [default port of WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which is 443 if you don't add a port suffix by your own. If you run it on a non-default one (8080) you need the port suffix.

Comment: So I could add support for http (80) and redirect to https (443)?

Comment: Hm I think I misread your anwser. You mean that wss://ws.site.com secretly adds 443 as the port? How can I fix this? It works here https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, how do they do it?

Comment: @tbleckert No secret here. The default port for wss is 443, like it is for https. You can specify another port if you want both cases.

Comment: You mean I need to run node directly on port 443?

Comment: what should be changed in this .conf file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your settings.

Your upstream is running on port 8080:

```
upstream ws.site.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

And you are telling to look on https (443) port:

```
proxy_pass https://ws.site.com;
proxy_redirect off;
```

Fix it with `http://ws.site.com`

Simple port table:

- port 80:  http,  ws
- port 443: https, wss